# Dropbox API - Get permanent link for my media?

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I use "createTemporaryDirectLink" method to get links for streaming my video. it works like a charm... but every time I need to update these links as they expire.

I wonder whether there is a possibility to get and then keep permanent links for streaming media?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might want to instead get a share link via [createShareableLink](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) and then convert it to a direct link by stripping the other query parameters and adding `raw=1`. (See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 for details on how to manipulate share links.)

Comment: Thank you very much @smarx I needed this very badly. A note I wanted to add was if you do the api call yourself, make sure to send `short_url=false` as this `?raw=1` trick won't work on the short url.

Comment: Hey @smarx do you know if there is something similar for Onedrive?

Comment: @Noitidart Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Hey there @smarx I was doing same technique with API v2 - I was wondering if there was a documented way to do this? It seems appending `?raw=1` does indeed give the value I can put in `<img src="....">` however it seems to load slowly due to a redirect to  `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/MKpDsr5tbxRnKIIubzVVhJYnt92gcz5KQLqjU292mlNEdGLKPJGuK6OpN30Yu9w4/file`. The original was `https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjo9trltuusrbzz/Screenshot%20-%20Feb%2026%2C%202016%202%3A36%20PM.png?dl=0&raw=1`. I havent tried `short_url` with `create_shared_link_settigns` but can `raw=1` apply to short?