# Dropbox - API get the download link of a file

Tags: dropbox-api

I have a web app where user can upload a picture of his logo
using dropbox api im able to save the file to a dropbox folder which is great

however i want to get the download link so using my angular client ill be able to set the img src tag and show the image

I've been using this implementation:

```
String url = client.sharing().createSharedLinkWithSettings("/" + clientId + "/logo." + fileName[1]).getUrl();
```

however as the name implies im getting a share link which is basically a web page with the image
i only need the image
is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer @Greg gave is correct but i needed a permanent link i was able to use the answer from here
[Dropbox API - Get permanent link for my media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669173/dropbox-api-get-permanent-link-for-my-media)

and here is my implementation

```
String[] fileName = file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.");
InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
client.files().uploadBuilder("/" + clientId + "/logo." + fileName[1]).withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE).uploadAndFinish(in);
log.debug("Successfully uploaded image to drop box account");
SharedLinkMetadata meta = client.sharing().createSharedLinkWithSettings("/" + clientId + "/logo." + fileName[1]);
String url = meta.getUrl();
// now we need to strip any other url params and append raw=1;
url = url.split("\\?")[0];
url = url + "\\?raw=1";
```

Comment: Note that per [the help article](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download), it's best to fully parse the URL in order to modify the parameters, instead of just performing raw string modifications like this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use [`DbxUserFilesRequests.getTemporaryLink`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#getTemporaryLink-java.lang.String-) instead. That will give you a temporary link that points directly to the file data.

Comment: i had to unmark the answer since as stated its a temporary link and after few hours i get 410 from dropbox. what i need is a permanent link

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and was much easier than the solutions above, [per this article](https://zapier.com/blog/generate-direct-dropbox-link/):

> To get a direct download link, replace the [www.dropbox.com](http://www.dropbox.com) with dl.dropboxusercontent.com

EDIT: I've also discovered that you can add the query parameter `?dl=1` (dl meaning download and 1 meaning "enabled") to a shared link and that will make it a direct-download link as well. This is likely more reliable (long-term) than the method above.

Comment: This answer is way too underrated! The entire damn internet is looking for this solution. LOL!! Thanks @Preston Badeer